# C# constructing generic method

Tags: c#, runtime, generics

```
var leftCurrent = leftArray.GetValue(i);
var rightCurrent = rightArray.GetValue(i);

var mi = typeof (PropertyCompare).GetMethod("NotEqualProperties");
mi.MakeGenericMethod(leftCurrent.GetType());

var notEqualProps = mi.Invoke(null,new []{leftCurrent, rightCurrent});

if(notEqualProps != null) 
    result.Add(new ArraysDiffResult(i, notEqualProps as List<string>));
```

Why does this code throws InvalidOperationException ( Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true.) ?

NotEqualProperties is static generic method..

UPD : I've already found solution. Just forgot to assign new MethodInfo...(Epic Fail..)

*But how about performance?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MakeGenericMethod` returns a new `MethodInfo` instance.  (`MethodInfo` is immutable)

Your code creates this new instance, throws it away, then continues using the open (non-parameterized) `MethodInfo`.

You need to use the new instance, like this:

```
mi = mi.MakeGenericMethod(leftCurrent.GetType());
```

---

Yes; reflection is much slower than normal method calls.
However, unless you're calling it in a tight loop, it's not necessarily an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't assign the result of

```
mi.MakeGenericMethod(leftCurrent.GetType());
```

to anything. Note that `MakeGenericMethod` does not mutate the invoking instance.

> P.S Is this code much slower than calling method directly (without mi.Invoke) ?

Much? I don't know. The only way to know is to set performance benchmarks and to profile.

Comment: Could you please share some links to VS profiler reviews/tutorials/samples ?

Comment: @taras.roshko: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=nant+profiler+tutorial#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=ants+profiler+tutorial+review&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=1 (I'm not trying to be a jerk here, I just don't know any specific reviews/tutorials/samples that are good. I can tell you that ANTS is very easy to use.)

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I'm stupid...It should be :

```
mi = mi.MakeGenericMethod(leftCurrent.GetType());
```

(Facepalm...).
But how about performance?